# List all queries connected through ado connection

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ado, vcl

I have application that has ADO connection on main form and several plugins that have ADO queries which I connect to this main connection. One problem is that I can't properly design those plugins without their personal connection which becomes messy when I connect plugins to main app. One plugin has plenty of queries.

I can use `ConnectionObject` to pass plugin's queries through main connection, but this is non-convenient for me, because when main connection needs to reconnect, I can't automatically reconnect all the queries. So I have to reassign those plugins' `Connection` property to main connection after plugin creation.

I know that one can list all active queries using ADOConnection's `DataSets` property. But what property should I use if I want to list both active and inactive DataSets? The IDE lists them automatically in designer, so I think there should be a generic way to do this.

Comment: I've checked and indexed property `DataSets` is a collection of all datasets (active and inactive) linked to a given connection. You would have to provide us some code if it does not work for you.

Comment: Indeed. Yesterday I didn't check how does `TADOConnection.RegisterClient` method work. Today I found that you are right. Though guides that I found over Internet told me straight that `DataSets` are only active datasets. Anyway, you can post your comment as correct answer.

Comment: Done, I've extended my answer a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps documentation regarding `TADOConnection.DataSets` which can be found [here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOConnection_DataSets.html) has confused you.

It says:

> Use DataSets to access active datasets associated with a connection
>   component.

This might leed to thinking that `DataSets` keeps only active datasets which is not the case. To test this, just put one `TADOConnection` and one `TADOQuery` component on a form and set up `TADOQuery.Connection` to the instance of your connection, for example `ADOConnection1`.

To test that `DataSets` property keeps also inactive datasets you might use this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ADOConnection1.DataSetCount - 1 do
  begin
    if not ADOConnection1.DataSets[i].Active then
      ShowMessage('Inactive dataset!');
  end;
end;
```